# What's the meaning of the expression verb + "ikitai to omoimasu"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I found that the expression **verb + "wo yaritai to omoimasu**" means **"I think I want to do" + verb**, which makes sense to me.

However, I am not sure about the similar expression **verb + "wo ikitai to omoimasu"**. "To omoimasu" is "I think", "-tai" tells me "I want", but "iku" is "to go". Is this giving some sense of future like the [English expression "going to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/110821/363747), or what?

When I tried to guess the meaning, assuming that it was like the English "going to", I got:

> "I think I want to + "going to"

But I don't know how to translate it correctly. What is the meaning of the expression, is it "I think I'm going to do something"? Is it "I think I want to do something?" or is it something else?

What's the exact translation of the expression **verb + "ikitai to omoimasu"**?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you're referring to or links to pages discussing it? I'm having a hard time imagining something like what you're describing.

Comment: You really saw `verb + を行く`, not `noun + を行く`? The particle を does not take a verb outside some rare archaic constructions. [行く has many usages](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F), some of which do take を. Anyway, your question is too generalized to provide a concise answer. Please share a specific example sentence.

Comment: Or perhaps you saw the base word of a サ変 verb (which is a noun by the way) and then を行いたい, with the word there being おこなう?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About the syntax

If you want to combine any given verb with [行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i} (or [行]{i}く{ku}, for that matter), you should:

1. Use the so-called **masu stem** (or more appropiately [連]{ren}[用]{you}[形]{kei}) of the verb. For example, for the verb [食]{ta}べ{be}る{ru}:

> [食]{ta}べ{be}る{ru} → [食]{ta}べ{be}ま{ma}す{su} → [食]{ta}べ{be}<s>ます</s> → [食]{ta}べ{be}

2. Use the **particle に{ni}**, not the particle を{wo}:

> [ラー]{raa}メ{me}ン{n}　を{wo}　[食]{ta}べ{be}　**に{ni}**　[行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i}。 [I] want to go eat ramen.

Note that in the example sentence, the particle を{wo} is **not** joining [食]{ta}べ{be} and [行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i}, but it is still necessary to join [ラー]{raa}メ{me}ン{n} and [食]{ta}べ{be}. The important particle to join [食]{ta}べ{be} and [行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i} is **the particle に{ni}**.

Finally, と{to} [思]{omo}い{i}ま{ma}す{su} adds the meaning "[I] think":

> [ラー]{raa}メ{me}ン{n}　を{wo}　[食]{ta}べ{be}　に{ni}　[行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i} と{to} [思]{omo}い{i}ま{ma}す{su}。 [I] think [I] want to go eat ramen.

---

### About the meaning

The meaning of the expression ~ + に{ni}　[行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i} と{to} [思]{omo}い{i}ま{ma}す{su} is "I think I want to do ~". Although ~ + に{ni}　[行]{i}き{ki}た{ta}い{i} formally resembles the expression "going to" in English, it doesn't add any sense of future.

---

### A note on "Verb + を{wo}"

As others have pointed out in the comments section, the construction Verb + を{wo} is not possible in general. Please clarify if you indeed were asking specifically about Verb + を{wo}, or if on the contrary, the first part of this post answers your question.